# How does everyone manage archiving/deleting documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, archiving

I'm currently learning a lot about the MEAN stack and obviously MongoDB. I want to set my database up so that nothing is ever 'removed', things are only marked as deleted or moved somewhere else, like an archived collection/database. What's the industry standard way of doing this?

The way i see it is that I have two options, both raising more questions:

1. Marking documents as deleted with a deleted key.

   Would I store this as a timestamp with an accompanying array of timestamps? The array is needed as I'm wanting to also create a 'restoring' functionality, in-turn meaning it can be deleted more than once which I want to track. This will mean that I have to update a lot of my queries to ignore that key.
2. Move the documents to another collection or database.

   This would require the most work as I'd need to handle any other functionality that references that document. For example deleting a user from a cinema database, would this mean that I have to archive previous bookings as well or just update queries to also search in the archive?

I couldn't find any useful resources on this but if you guys know of any then please point me in that direction :) thanks.

Comment: Actually, there is not a "standard" way to do this. Each company does it by its own way. For your first option, you don't need to store a timestamp array but just a flag indicating that document is "deleted". Then, in another collection you can store the events. For instance: `{event: "deleted", date: "03/08/2017 08:00:00", documentId: "7726"}` An event store is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks hector! his answer:

"Actually, there is not a "standard" way to do this. Each company does it by its own way. For your first option, you don't need to store a timestamp array but just a flag indicating that document is "deleted". Then, in another collection you can store the events. For instance: {event: "deleted", date: "03/08/2017 08:00:00", documentId: "7726"} An event store is the way to go"